# getting integer from string with formatted number

Tags: objective-c

I have a string representing a number, and I want to convert it an NSInteger. The problem is, that the string is formatted with thousand separators:

```
"1,234"
```

when using [value intValue], I get 1 as the value.

Is it because it thinks the thousand separator is a decimal separator? (my locale uses comma as decimal separator and a space or a dot as thousand separator)

How can I ensure that I get the right number?

-Vegar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class which can not only encode numbers, but also decode them according to the current locale.

Comment: By setting the positive number format to @"#,##0", I get the right number.  
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would find a class that can decode numbers from strings just as Georg suggests, but a quick solution could also be to chop off the extra thousand separators using the [stringByReplacing…](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:) method of the `NSString` class.